Enumerate all data in Excel range, count them and sort by occurrence
I have a range "G2:N" & Lastrow. I want to enumerate all data >1 from these cells, put them apart and count them in the next column and then sort them decreased by the time of occurrences, each.
I found this code, to put these eight columns into one column. I am not able to count them and put them into a table, separately.
Sub MoveData()

START_ROW = 2
START_COL = 7
STEP_COL = 1
OUTPUT_ROW = 2
OUTPUT_COL = 32

Row = START_ROW
Col = START_COL
Out_Row = OUTPUT_ROW
While Col < 15
    While Row < Lastrow
        If Cells(Row, Col).Value <> "" Then
            Cells(Out_Row, OUTPUT_COL).Value = Cells(Row, Col).Value
            Out_Row = Out_Row + 1
        End If
        Row = Row + 1
    Wend
    Row = START_ROW
    Col = Col + STEP_COL
Wend
End Sub

Data example:


Please, add data example so we can reproduce your issue. All I could find in internet was this code Try to develop your own code. You can start using the macro recorder and learn

@FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns I added a picture with data examples

[Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?]
(https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).
Please create MD table with online tool Table Generator.


Load data table into array
Loop through data and count it with a Dictionary object

Microsoft documentation:

Range.CurrentRegion property (Excel)


Range.End property (Excel)


Range.Sort method (Excel)

Sub Demo()
    Dim objDic As Object, rngData As Range
    Dim i As Long, sKey As String, j As Long
    Dim arrData
    Dim oSht As Worksheet
    Set oSht = Sheets("Sheet1")  ' modify as needed
    Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set rngData = oSht.Range("G2:N" & Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row)
    arrData = rngData.Value
    For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
        For j = LBound(arrData, 2) To UBound(arrData, 2)
            sKey = arrData(i, j)
            If Val(sKey) > 1 Then
                If objDic.exists(sKey) Then
                    objDic(sKey) = objDic(sKey) + 1
                Else
                    objDic(sKey) = 1
                End If
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    Sheets.Add
    Range("A1:B1") = Array("Value", "Count")
    Range("A2").Resize(objDic.Count, 1) = Application.Transpose(objDic.keys)
    Range("B2").Resize(objDic.Count, 1) = Application.Transpose(objDic.items)
    Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Sort Key1:=Columns(2), order1:=xlDescending
    Set objDic = Nothing
End Sub

